# How to check the privileges on certain schemas for certain roles? PSQL PGADMIN4

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema, pgadmin-4

after creating 4 roles and assigning them privileges on some schemas i want to check if I did it right, but i just can't.

I used the following code to see said privileges:

```
SELECT 
    privilege_type
    , table_schema
    , table_name
from information_schema.role_table_grants
where grantee in('gerent','administratiu','metge','tecnic')
and table_schema in ('laboratori','administracio','clinica')
```

[image: this is the output i get]

I supposed I did something right while creating my user because the code works but I just get back "locked" info even with the "postgres" user. Is there an alternative way?
thanks :)

Comment: posthre is very picky, it allows you only to access data frm the schema you connected to